# Rust module weird behavior with multiple use from different file

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I thought I understood Rust modules, but I am completely lost with `mod` inconsistencies, at least with my own level of understanding.

I have the following folder structure in my project:

```
project
|
 - src
   |- main.rs
   |- mod.rs
   |- common
     |- error.rs
     |- global.rs
     |- ids.rs
     |- mod.rs
   - user_info
     |- user.rs
     |- admin.rs
     |- mod.rs
   - data_source
     |- data_src.rs
     |- data_bridge.rs
     |- data_copies.rs
     |- mod.rs
```

As you may see all folders have a mod.rs file, which basically contains `pub mod` declaration to all the sub-folders or folder-level files in it. Thought that would make importing cleaner.

data_src.rs is importing modules using

```
use super::*;
use super::super::common::*
```

data_src.rs is specifically has dependencies on

```
data_source/data_bridge.rs
common/error.rs
common/global.rs
```

data_copies.rs is importing modules using

```
use super::*;
use super::super::common::*
```

And data_copies.rs has dependencies on

```
data_source/data_src.rs
data_source/data_bridge.rs
common/error.rs
common/global.rs
common/ids.rs
```

While compiling using `cargo build` command I am seeing no errors from data_src.rs, but same is not true for data_copies.rs, where I keep seeing the same error:

```
use of undeclared crate or module "..."
```

across all the imported functions from all the files.

This is very unreasonable for me, because I am using the same `use` command to import mods in data_src.rs file where it does not throw any error, but only in  data_copies.rs.

I checked online, but I cannot find any theaory or explaination remotely helping me understand the problem. Can someone tell me what is going on.

Comment: And yes, if `data_src` and `data_bridge` are declared in the typical way, then yes they should act nearly identically. Can you share how you've declared them? Are you using `mod` in `data_source/mod.rs`?

Comment: @kmdreko conside that an typo in writing the snippent. Rest assured it is compiled check for incorrect syntax.

Comment: @kmdreko yes, I am using ```pub mod``` in the data_source/mod.rs

Comment: do you try importing using absolute paths like `use crate::common::*`?

Comment: @al3x I get error unresolved import `crate::common`

Comment: try deleting the `src/mod.rs` file.. or renaming

Comment: @al3x nothing different, same issue.

Comment: are you declaring your modules inside your `main.rs` like `mod data_source;`?, if your declaring  your top level modules inside `src/mod.rs` instead of `src/main.rs` cargo compiler will not know how to import them

Comment: @al3x yes indeed, and that is exactly causing the error! Wow.. Thank you for your help! If you can leave answer, I will accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust has two kinds of crates, binaries and libraries.

A binary is a crate that has an entry point and runs directly in the machine. And library is a crate that doesn't has an entry point, is a crate that can be used in other crates.

When you're writing crates cargo starts reading it from the main file, which is `src/main.rs` for binaries, and `src/lib.rs` for libraries.

Although the modules are declared through `rs` files which same name as the module, or through a folder with a `mod.rs` file. The top level modules need be declared in the `main` file, and this is your problem.

Your problem is you're declaring your top level in `src/mod.rs` and cargo don't know how to import them, all you need is move your top level declaration to `src/main.rs` instead of `src/mod.rs`.

Comment: Thank you @al3x for you help and detailed explaination.